# How to get different latitude and longitude while moving for every 1 minute in android?

Tags: java, android, gps, location, geopoints

now i am working with GPS for getting different latitude and longitude for every 1 minute while moving and that has to be stored into array list. I am using thread for this. I followed this link. http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/

And my code is

Tracking.java

```
package com.example.getlatlang;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Tracking extends Activity 
{

Button btnShowLocation;
boolean isRepeat = true;
 protected int splashTime = 1000;

 int timer =0;
Thread th;
ArrayList<Double> lat_array = new ArrayList<Double>();
ArrayList<Double> lon_array = new ArrayList<Double>();
// GPSTracker class
GPSTracker gps;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.currentlocation);

    btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_bt);

    // show location button click event
    btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0)
        {       
            // create class object

            if(isRepeat)
            {
                isRepeat = false;
                btnShowLocation.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.stop);
                if(lat_array.size()>0 && lon_array.size()>0)
                {
                    lat_array.clear();
                    lon_array.clear();
                    System.out.println("Array cleared...");
                }
            // check if GPS enabled th=new Thread()
                th=new Thread()
                 {
                     @Override
                        public void run(){
                            try
                            {
                               for (timer = 0; timer < 20; timer++)
                               {
                                   // int waited = 0;
                                  //  while(waited < splashTime)
                                  //  {
                                        Thread.sleep(100);
                                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                                        {
                                            @Override
                                            public void run()
                                            {
                                                try
                                                {    gps = new GPSTracker(Tracking.this);
                                                    if(gps.canGetLocation())
                                                    {

                                                        double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                                                        double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

                                                        lat_array.add(latitude);

                                                        lon_array.add(longitude);
                                                        // \n is for new line
                                                        System.out.println("lat_array"+lat_array+"lon_array"+lon_array);
                                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + lat_array + "\nLong: " + lon_array, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    {
                                                        // can't get location
                                                        // GPS or Network is not enabled
                                                        // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
                                                        gps.showSettingsAlert();
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                catch(Exception e)
                                                {
                                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
                                    //  waited += 100;
                                    //}
                               }}
                           catch (InterruptedException e)
                           {
                            }

                        }
                    };
                    th.start();

                }


            else
            {

                isRepeat = true;                      
                th.interrupt();
                btnShowLocation.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.start);

            }
        }
    });
}
public void ohDestroy()
{
     th.stop();
}
}
```

GPSTracker.java

```
package com.example.getlatlang;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;

 public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener
 {

private final Context mContext;

// flag for GPS status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

// flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

// flag for GPS status
boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location; // location
double latitude; // latitude
double longitude; // longitude

// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GPSTracker(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
}

public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}

/**
 * Stop using GPS listener
 * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
 * */
public void stopUsingGPS(){
    if(locationManager != null){
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
    }       
}

/**
 * Function to get latitude
 * */
public double getLatitude(){
    if(location != null){
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    // return latitude
    return latitude;
}

/**
 * Function to get longitude
 * */
public double getLongitude(){
    if(location != null){
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    // return longitude
    return longitude;
}

/**
 * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
 * @return boolean
 * */
public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

/**
 * Function to show settings alert dialog
 * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
 * */
public void showSettingsAlert(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

 }
```

Now my issue is can't able to get different latitude and longitude points while moving. The first value only stored into an array for 20 times. Because i am setting the Tread must be run 20 times like that. But i want to get different points and stored into an array list. I don't know where i did the mistake. Can any body help me to resolve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: use a scheduler and service

Answer (score 1):

Apply this. It will refresh every 10 seconds.

```
Handler  mHandler1 = new Handler();

new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
                mHandler1.post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



                        // creating GPS Class object
                    GPSTracker gps = new GPSTracker (Tracking .this);

                        // check if GPS location have some values
                        if (gps.canGetLocation()) {

                            double currentlat = gps.getLatitude();
                            double currentlong = gps.getLongitude();



                        } else {
                            // no current location
                            gps.showSettingsAlert();
                        }
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        }
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: I have changed pls have look at it.

Answer (score 1):

you have used `sleep(100)` on the loop of collecting latitude.
The unit of time is micro-second here.(as far as i know)
20*100 = 2000 which is just 2 second. and i don't think GPS update that fast.
Have a look at this.
Rather you can use the same loop but store the value only if it is different from previous one.

```
if(oldLat != curLat){
  //store curLat to array
  //and make oldLat = curLat
}
```

Comment: Agree, we can ask app to refresh/update every 2 seconds (at application level) but it doesn't guarantee that for every refresh interval, the subsequent GPS "position fix" or "hot start" (TTSF) can occur every 2 seconds (at device level); it depends on the availability of already stored satellite information to immediately lock a GPS position. Not many GPS receivers can achieve that very fast TTSF.. This one claims it can do "hot start" every 2 seconds https://www.linxtechnologies.com/resources/data-guides/rxm-gps-sr.pdf (definitely not for smartphone design)